# Optional parameter in angular route. Use angular route or ui-route?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following ng-route:

```
'/posts/:category'
```

How can I make category optional?

Does anyone knows where is the pattern match docs for ng-route?

And is it better to use ui-router instead of ng-route?

Comment: Both ui-router and ngroute support using variables in your path so they are both suited for the job. It depends on your other requirements to see which is best for you situation, [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example) is the example for ngroute.

Comment: You might be better of telling us what is not working and what you're trying to do. Since your url already has category as a optional parameter

Comment: I didn't realize that angular would consider :category optional ... But basically I need to map server side routes to angular routes. But server side routes are different from angular routes so I need to know all available patterns for angular routes to try to create a mapping between angular routes and server side routes.

Comment: So you're saying that your serverside routes are dynamic? You can't simply match them by using the optional parameters?

Comment: No, I am saying that I am translating routes on a multilanguage web application but because an option parameter in an Angular Route String has a different format from an Optional parameter in a Server Side Route string then I need to convert one to another. I mean the route patterns / rules ... So I was looking for all the patterns in Angule NgRoute but can't find the page. Does anyone knows where is it?

Comment: BTW, in angular an optional route is represented by  "/posts/:category" in server side is represented by "/posts/{category?}" ... So I need to create such conversions ...